# XStorable storeToURL and WebDav

Tags: java, liferay, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I have seen multiple threads regarding the use of XStorable.storeToURL and vnd.sun.star.webdav://domain:8080//path/to/document_library to save OO documents to a webdav library folder. However, I have not seen a posting where someone has successfully used this in Java. While the use of the UCB vnd.sun.star.webdav://domain:8080//path/to/document_library/doc.odt works when using the File, Save menu options within OO Writer, I am prompted for a username and password. Supplying user and password via vnd.sun.star.webdav://user:password@domain:8080/ has not worked for me. I need to use this method from within a Java class to save a OO document. Has anyone had success using the following or something similar?

```
xStorable.storeToURL("vnd.sun.star.webdav://domain:8080/path/to/document_library/doc.odt", storeProps)
```

In the OO Developer's Guide, there is a paragraph regarding WebDav authentication:

> DAV resources that require authentication are accessed using the interaction handler mechanism of the UCB. The DAV content calls an interaction handler supplied by the client to let it handle an authentication request. The implementation of the interaction handler collects the user name or password from a location, for example, a login dialog, and supplies this data as an interaction response.

Maybe this is related to the issue?  If so, how to use an interaction handler for the authentication when trying to storeToURL via webdav?

Answer (score 0):

Adding InteractionHandler was the issue.  With this added, documents can be saved via storeToURL and passing the handler in as an argument:

```
String oooExeFolder = "C:/OpenOffice/program";
XComponentContext xLocalContext = BootstrapSocketConnector.bootstrap(oooExeFolder);
Object serviceManager = xLocalServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.task.InteractionHandler", xLocalContext); 
XInteractionHandler xHandler = (XInteractionHandler)UnoRuntime.queryInterface( XInteractionHandler.class, serviceManager);
PropertyValue[] storeProps = new PropertyValue[1];
storeProps[0] = new PropertyValue();
storeProps[0].Name  = "InteractionHandler";
storeProps[0].Value = xHandler;
xStorable.storeToURL("vnd.sun.star.webdav://domain:8080/path/to/document_library/doc.odt", storeProps);
```